# CouchDB design view not returning all the records older than N seconds

Tags: couchdb

I'm experiencing a problem using CouchDB design which should return records older than 5 seconds based on `created` property of documents. The documents are continuously added to the `mydb` database.

For some reason the documents with lesser created date than current date - 5 seconds are not returned.

This is how I add a document:

```
...
timestamp==$(echo $(( $(date +%s) * 1000 )))
...
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"created\": ${timestamp}}" http://localhost:5984/mydb -u "admin:YOURPASSWORD"
```

How I query using the view:

```
curl -X GET -u "admin:YOURPASSWORD" "http://localhost:5984/mydb/_design/nonce/_view/older_than?limit=100"
```

If added just a few documents, then things work ok, but repeatedly doing so it doesn't returned expected number of records.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Here is the example project specifically created to learn what I'm doing wrong on GitHub (above examples automated and a corresponding GO method that should delete returned records:

https://github.com/igorrendulic/couchdb-test

Comment: Your expectation is not clear.  Are you expecting a result set composed of most recent  documents less than *literally* now (time of query) less 5 seconds? Because with your bare query `limit` paired with collation will always return the oldest 100 documents in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is key to understand that the `emit` function is invoked during indexing of a document at creation or update time *rather than* at query time.

The emit function

```js
function(doc) 
{ 
    var now = Date.now() - (5 * 1000);
    if (doc.created < now) {
        emit(doc.created, doc._rev); 
    }
}
```

Is subtracting 5 seconds from the document's `created` field (notably assuming that field exists) and indexing the value, which does not seem useful.

If the solution is to return the most recent documents that have a `created` field value that is 5 or more seconds less than current time, then this simple `emit` will suffice (and may provide more utility for other queries)

```js
function(doc) 
{    
    if (doc.created) {
        emit(doc.created, doc._rev); 
    }
}
```

CouchDB's [collation specification](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#collation-specification) result in smaller numeric values to be at the beginning of the index so the query needs to reverse the sort and provide the desired window of time, say in this case current time less 5 seconds:

```
?descending=true&start_key={epoch_time_ms}&limit=100
```

That query will return up to 100 documents with `created` less than or equal to `epoch_time_ms` with the most recent document first in the result set.

I must add, storing the `_rev` seems nebulous as that information can be gained from the result document.

Comment: Your answer prompted me to delve deeper into the CouchDB documentation reminding me not to make assumptions about how things work. I realized that my knowledge of indexing and using Google's datastore led me down the path of many assumptions. 

I apologize for any time I may have wasted. I'm very grateful for your helpful response and your patience.

Comment: After having worked with RDMS/SQL for decades, CouchDB was a steep learning curve in many ways.  I recommend delving into the B-Tree index used by CouchDB, particularly the documentation on [Reduce](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html#reduce-rereduce); view/index will become crystal clear, and really get you in the saddle!